# Is it possible to set a SharePoint Online list as read only without having to edit permissions?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions, modern-experience, read-only

I have a list in SharePoint Online that I would like to make read-only. I would normally remove the edit permission from all roles in the list permissions, but I want to even prevent site-collection administrators from editing the list (of course, if they really needed to, they could just change the setting).

I can't find any property on the list object. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, site collection administrators will always have full control over lists and libraries in the site collection and therefore be able to edit the list.

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint Site Collection Administrator cannot be locked out of any sub-site, list, library, item, or page on the site. The permissions inheritance for any of these elements can be broken at any time, and permissions can be changed so that even users with Full Control rights have lesser permissions or even no permissions at all.

In all cases the **SharePoint Site Collection Administrator will always have full access to all of the elements and all of the data**. This is especially handy when a site Owner accidentally deletes their own user account or group when creating custom permissions.

**Reference**:

[What Is a SharePoint Site Collection Administrator?](https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/what-is-a-sharepoint-site-collection-administrator)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to prevent site collection administrator editing the list. Because site collection administrator has full control.